# ARRAY_AGG() grouped by another column's values

Tags: sql, arrays, database, postgresql, aggregate-functions

Here's my table like below

```
p_no  type  name  value
------------------------
1     A     Tomy  1
1     A     Nick  2
1     B     Tomy  3
1     B     Nick  4
1     C     Tomy  5
1     C     Nick  4
2     A     Tomy  8
2     A     Nick  7
2     B     Tomy  5
2     B     Nick  4
```

It means each `p_no` represents a block that records poeple's value in both `A, B, C` type (might be more types).

I want to select a person with his value of all types

Given `p_no=1, name=Tomy`

```
A    B    C    D
------------------
1    3    5    ..
```

I have tried

```sql
SELECT p_no, t[1] A, t[2] B/*, t[3] C.....*/
FROM (
    SELECT p_no, ARRAY_AGG(type) FILTER (WHERE name='Tomy') t
    FROM type
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY 1) _unused
```

but it cannnot make the ARRAY_AGG() include the value

**I think I need something similar to** `ARRAY_AGG('value' GROUP BY 'type')`

Is this kind of query possible or is there any better alternatives?

Comment: You are asking to pivot rows to a dynamically defined list of columns.  Mixing data and schema like this is not supported from within SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is right. You want to aggregate `value` ordered by `type`, so:

```sql
select p_no, t[1] as "A", t[2] as "B", t[3] as "C"
from (
    select p_no, array_agg(value order by type) as t
    from my_table
    where name = 'Tomy' 
    group by p_no
    ) s
```

[db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ff4e031e7ef3a0a4b208dba7f2caf78b)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, it works! It still needs `FILTER (WHERE name='name')` to work correctly.

Comment: Instead of `filter` I've added a condition in the where clause which looks simpler and works the same (in this case).

Comment: Oh, sorry for omitting the where condition. I forgot to use it. Thanks again!